# Go, Golang : Program, Package Structure for Command Line Interface

Tags: go, package-managers, packagemaker

This is newbie question... Let's say I have a Go code in a directory(repository initiated here as root) called "myprogram". And I write some packages divided in several sub-directories.

Then I have

repository, root directory

**myprogram**
----------- package1
----------- package2
----------- package3

Then in the myprogram directory, I will write the code with main package for main program and the main program will call all the packages that are defined in the sub-directories, like the following:

main.go

```
import "github.com/username/package1"
import "github.com/username/package2"
import "github.com/username/package3"

func main() {
    package1.Function1()
    ....
}
```

Then I can just run this code with

```
$ go run main.go
```

I have no problem so far. But what if this program has some features with flags?

```
$ go run main.go  flag1 flag2
```

This works, but I want to run something like

```
$ myprogram
$ flag1
....
$ flag2
```

Since all the programs and source code will be contained under the directory myprogram which is also the name of the project, repository

**myprogram**
----------- package1
----------- package2
----------- package3

We run Vim with the command, something like this...

```
$ vim
```

To summarize, how do I make my program run by command, not by go run main ?

Is there any open source repository that I can refer to? Or please let me know the package or documentation to read. I tried

```
go install
```

But can't make it work like I wanted.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To expand on @FuZxxl's answer: `go run` should only ever be used for a quick, single-file check. Go isn't a scripting language, so you should be compiling it (go run effectively does that and discards the binary). When you have multiple files as part of the one package (either `package main` or `package mylibrary`) you'll need to use `go build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `go build`. This will create an executable of the package in the current directory. You can also run `go build <packagename>`, which creates a binary in `$GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: I was always confused by go build and go build packagename, so go build packagename, this is the one that creates the binary in GOPATH/bin right? not go build

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this one](https://github.com/go-easygen/wireframe#command-line-flag-handling-code-auto-generation)

- it is an open source repository that people can refer to
- it illustrates how to deal with the cases that the main program can have some sub features that need different flags
- and for sure it shows how to make programs run by command, not by go run main
- and most importantly, make the whole process as simple as possible by auto-generate all things that can be auto-generated